Failed to boot from mdadm RAID 1 partition
Environment

Hardware: a common X86_64 PC. There are two 4TB HDDs, /dev/sda and /dev/sdb.
OS: Anolis OS 23.1 (a variant of CentOS Stream like RockyLinux, so the behavior should be very similar).
Components:

grub2-common-1:2.12-8.an23.noarch
Grub2-efi-x64-1:2.12-8.an23.x86_64
shim-x64-15.8-1.an23.x86_64


The output of lsblk -f is:

NAME    FSTYPE            FSVER LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                                          
├─sda1  vfat              FAT16          3687-D3D5                             121.6M     5% /mnt/newraid/boot/efi
│                                                                                            /boot/efi
├─sda2  ext4              1.0            a8889be5-a5bf-4001-80fd-8cc5848b0f15    3.4T     0% /home
├─sda3  ext4              1.0            7ed59ca5-1062-4841-9eaf-5455de1ff527   16.3G    11% /
└─sda4  swap              1              7cb849cb-db1a-46da-a64b-5afffb1e7c4c                [SWAP]
sdb                                                                                          
├─sdb1  vfat              FAT16          75D0-F9B6                                           
├─sdb2  linux_raid_member 1.2   ZX-NAS:1 d2d58a60-b4fb-d792-5430-07603f85c090                
│ └─md1 ext4              1.0            24814373-7082-4290-986b-5f049e4d76dd    3.4T     0% /mnt/newraid/home
├─sdb3  linux_raid_member 1.2   ZX-NAS:0 ae686811-5489-4aa6-c48d-458fe0bbc232                
│ └─md0 ext4              1.0            d3984281-70f1-47fc-aaf0-8627d49ec68f   16.3G    11% /mnt/newraid
└─sdb4  swap              1              533b5b6a-5931-4fb0-b3ee-1152a62e6e11                

What I want to do

Copy all files from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb (which I've done by rsync).
Generate grub items for the OS on /dev/sdb.
Boot to the system on /dev/sdb so that I can finally add /dev/sda to the mdadm RAID1 array.

What I did

Mount all partitions:

mount /dev/md0 newraid
mount /dev/md1 newraid/home
mount /dev/sda1 newraid/boot/efi
mount --bind /dev newraid/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts newraid/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc newraid/proc
mount --bind /sys newraid/sys


chroot into the mounted directory and reinstall grub2 packages:

chroot newraid/
rm /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
rm /boot/efi/EFI/anolis/grub.cfg
dnf reinstall shim-* grub2-efi-* grub2-common

Related information (in chroot environment)

The contents of /etc/mdadm.conf:

DEVICE /dev/sda* /dev/sdb*
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=ZX-NAS:0 UUID=ae686811:54894aa6:c48d458f:e0bbc232
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=ZX-NAS:1 UUID=d2d58a60:b4fbd792:54300760:3f85c090


The output of grubby --info DEFAULT shows correct UUID of /dev/md0:

index=0
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-6.6.25-2.1.an23.x86_64"
args="ro resume=UUID=7cb849cb-db1a-46da-a64b-5afffb1e7c4c rhgb quiet"
root="UUID=d3984281-70f1-47fc-aaf0-8627d49ec68f"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-6.6.25-2.1.an23.x86_64.img $tuned_initrd"
title="Anolis OS (6.6.25-2.1.an23.x86_64) 23"
id="1e06d08a379c4b8eb7c36745cd33b690-6.6.25-2.1.an23.x86_64"


The contents of /boot/efi/EFI/anolis/grub.cfg:

search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=dev d3984281-70f1-47fc-aaf0-8627d49ec68f
set prefix=($dev)/boot/grub2
export $prefix
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg


The contents of /boot/grub2/grub.cfg:

#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub2-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
set pager=1

if [ -f ${config_directory}/grubenv ]; then
  load_env -f ${config_directory}/grubenv
elif [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="${saved_entry}"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

terminal_output console
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_tuned ###
set tuned_params=""
set tuned_initrd=""
### END /etc/grub.d/00_tuned ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/01_users ###
if [ -f ${prefix}/user.cfg ]; then
  source ${prefix}/user.cfg
  if [ -n "${GRUB2_PASSWORD}" ]; then
    set superusers="root"
    export superusers
    password_pbkdf2 root ${GRUB2_PASSWORD}
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/01_users ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/08_fallback_counting ###
insmod increment
# Check if boot_counter exists and boot_success=0 to activate this behaviour.
if [ -n "${boot_counter}" -a "${boot_success}" = "0" ]; then
  # if countdown has ended, choose to boot rollback deployment,
  # i.e. default=1 on OSTree-based systems.
  if  [ "${boot_counter}" = "0" -o "${boot_counter}" = "-1" ]; then
    set default=1
    set boot_counter=-1
  # otherwise decrement boot_counter
  else
    decrement boot_counter
  fi
  save_env boot_counter
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/08_fallback_counting ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod diskfilter
insmod mdraid1x
insmod ext2
set root='mduuid/ae68681154894aa6c48d458fe0bbc232'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='mduuid/ae68681154894aa6c48d458fe0bbc232'  d3984281-70f1-47fc-aaf0-8627d49ec68f
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d3984281-70f1-47fc-aaf0-8627d49ec68f
fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set boot='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=boot --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  3687-D3D5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=boot 3687-D3D5
fi

# This section was generated by a script. Do not modify the generated file - all changes
# will be lost the next time file is regenerated. Instead edit the BootLoaderSpec files.
#
# The blscfg command parses the BootLoaderSpec files stored in /boot/loader/entries and
# populates the boot menu. Please refer to the Boot Loader Specification documentation
# for the files format: https://systemd.io/BOOT_LOADER_SPECIFICATION/.

# The kernelopts variable should be defined in the grubenv file. But to ensure that menu
# entries populated from BootLoaderSpec files that use this variable work correctly even
# without a grubenv file, define a fallback kernelopts variable if this has not been set.
#
# The kernelopts variable in the grubenv file can be modified using the grubby tool or by
# executing the grub2-mkconfig tool. For the latter, the values of the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
# and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT options from /etc/default/grub file are used to set both
# the kernelopts variable in the grubenv file and the fallback kernelopts variable.
if [ -z "${kernelopts}" ]; then
  set kernelopts="root=UUID=d3984281-70f1-47fc-aaf0-8627d49ec68f ro resume=UUID=7cb849cb-db1a-46da-a64b-5afffb1e7c4c rhgb quiet "
fi

insmod blscfg
blscfg
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_reset_boot_success ###
# Hiding the menu is ok if last boot was ok or if this is a first boot attempt to boot the entry
if [ "${boot_success}" = "1" -o "${boot_indeterminate}" = "1" ]; then
  set menu_hide_ok=1
else
  set menu_hide_ok=0 
fi
# Reset boot_indeterminate after a successful boot
if [ "${boot_success}" = "1" ] ; then
  set boot_indeterminate=0
# Avoid boot_indeterminate causing the menu to be hidden more than once
elif [ "${boot_indeterminate}" = "1" ]; then
  set boot_indeterminate=2
fi
# Reset boot_success for current boot 
set boot_success=0
save_env boot_success boot_indeterminate
### END /etc/grub.d/10_reset_boot_success ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/12_menu_auto_hide ###
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  if [ "${menu_show_once}" ]; then
    unset menu_show_once
    save_env menu_show_once
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=60
  elif [ "${menu_auto_hide}" -a "${menu_hide_ok}" = "1" ]; then
    set orig_timeout_style=${timeout_style}
    set orig_timeout=${timeout}
    if [ "${fastboot}" = "1" ]; then
      # timeout_style=menu + timeout=0 avoids the countdown code keypress check
      set timeout_style=menu
      set timeout=0
    else
      set timeout_style=hidden
      set timeout=1
    fi
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/12_menu_auto_hide ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/14_menu_show_once ###
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ]; then
  if [ "${menu_show_once_timeout}" ]; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout="${menu_show_once_timeout}"
    unset menu_show_once_timeout
    save_env menu_show_once_timeout
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/14_menu_show_once ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_ppc_terminfo ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_ppc_terminfo ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
  insmod bli
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
    menuentry 'Anolis OS 23 (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.6.25-2.1.an23.x86_64--7ed59ca5-1062-4841-9eaf-5455de1ff527' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  7ed59ca5-1062-4841-9eaf-5455de1ff527
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7ed59ca5-1062-4841-9eaf-5455de1ff527
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.6.25-2.1.an23.x86_64 root=/dev/sda3
        initrd /boot/initramfs-6.6.25-2.1.an23.x86_64.img
    }
    menuentry 'Anolis OS 23 (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-1e06d08a379c4b8eb7c36745cd33b690--7ed59ca5-1062-4841-9eaf-5455de1ff527' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  7ed59ca5-1062-4841-9eaf-5455de1ff527
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7ed59ca5-1062-4841-9eaf-5455de1ff527
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-1e06d08a379c4b8eb7c36745cd33b690 root=/dev/sda3
        initrd /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-1e06d08a379c4b8eb7c36745cd33b690.img
    }

# Other OS found, undo autohiding of menu unless menu_auto_hide=2
if [ "${orig_timeout_style}" -a "${menu_auto_hide}" != "2" ]; then
  set timeout_style=${orig_timeout_style}
  set timeout=${orig_timeout}
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
    fwsetup --is-supported
    if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
        menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
            fwsetup
        }
    fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

Error I got

The booting process was stuck at finding /dev/md0.
The timeout is FOREVER

What I have tried

Changing the paths of mdadm partitions in /etc/fstab from UUID to /dev/md0(1) does not work.
dracut --regenerate-all -f does not work.
Since it is impossible to boot successfully, logs of dmesg or journalctl are not available.
I tried to boot the system inside /dev/md0 through GRUB command line directly. The boot process is still stuck at finding /dev/md0.


Under chroot status, I added following text to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in /etc/default/grub:
rd.auto rd.md=1 rd.md.conf=1

then run
rm -f /boot/grub2/grub.cfg && rm -f /boot/efi/EFI/anolis/grub.cfg
dnf reinstall shim-* grub2-efi-* grub2-common

Now I can finally boot into the OS inside the mdadm partition.
FYI:

According to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html , by default Linux with dracut WILL NOT assemble ANY mdadm partition while booting. We MUST enable it by ourselves.
md-mod.start_dirty_degraded=1 has nothing to do with this problem. Actually, according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/md.html ,md-mod.start_dirty_degraded=1 only works for RAID 5/6.

